# How to set Editor's placeholder and borderstyle in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Editor has no placeholder property，maybe i should try to make a customized Editor control？
thank you!

```
<Editor x:Name="Editor1" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged" Margin="5">
</Editor>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Editor has no Placeholder property, unfortunately =/.

Some alternatives is showed [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20616/placeholder-editor), like to use a custom renderer.